# Покажите, как создать DLL со строками на C++

Tags: c++, dll

Пробовала разные варианты создания на выходе файла DLL, который содержит несколько строк, поскольку изучаю C# - C++ непонятен совсем.

Покажите пожалуйста код для создания C++ DLL, которая будет содержать пару строк (string или int), чтобы при обращении к ней, к определенному методу - возвращало ту или иную строку.

Код:

```
File.h
#include <string>
std::string String_One();
std::string String_Two(); 


File.cpp
#include "Windows.h"
#include "WowSuite.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    std::string String_One()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    std::string String_Two()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
```

Так возможно?

Comment: А в чём беда `_export  char* getString(){ return "Пара\nСтрок";};`  и `_export int getInt(){return 10;};`

Comment: Остальное - опции компилятора. Проще всего проэкт - создать - с++ - dll библиотека (и в борланде и в студии и в многих других). В вопросе стоит указать вашу IDE или компилятор (если командной строкой создаёте) т.к в разных версиях и фирмах есть свои особенности. Возможно язык IDE (бывают русские и английские среды). Т.к. вы разработчик c# у вас MS visual studio? Английская? Какая версия 2005 или 2014?

Comment: для меня с++ это дремучий лес. Я не понимаю про заголовки, про создание функций, к которым я буду обращаться, все, что мне (желательно) нужно - это проект, в котором содержится метод, отображающий определенный текст(таких методов будет несколько.)  После чего я хочу подключить эту библиотеку dll в c# и использовать метод, отображающий нужную мне строку

Comment: Для студии вот http://microsin.net/programming/pc/dll-building-and-using.html  Если не подходит **укажите** какая у вас **IDE**.

Comment: Ссылка помогла создать dll файл, но я не понимаю ккак создать свой метод, который будет содержать строку, которую я хочу получить

Comment: Так `__declspec(dllexport)  char* MyMethod(){ return "Строка которую хочу получить";};` ели вне класса. Вне класса проще.

Comment: Я не понимаю как с этим работать (((  Добавила код в File.h, а что делать с ним или как создать метод в cpp и надо ли это, я не понимаю..

Comment: мне нужна dll, которая будет содержать string и int параметры, которые я буду извлекать в своем c# коде

Comment: в заголвке h файле мы делаем партатипы фун-й обычно это выглядит как  string myfinc(string a, string b);  в cpp файле описываются паратипы  string myfinc(string a, string b){ string c = a+b; return c;}

Comment: В коде все хорошо только если вы используете это using namespace std;  то при вызове string вам std не нужен? вы в usinge  уже сказили что используете это пространство имен.

Comment: и еще момент все заголовчные файлы подключа.тся в H файле а в cpp вам нужен только #include "File.h"

Comment: @Елизавета, вам нужен метод или фун-я??

Comment: Что угодно, лишь бы я смогла обратиться к библиотеке извне и получить нужную мне строку

Comment: @Елизавета смотрите в ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

file.h

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#if defined(MYLIBRARY)
    #define LIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define LIBRARY_EXPORT
#endif

#include <string>

std::string LIBRARY_EXPORT String_One();
std::string LIBRARY_EXPORT String_Two();

#endif // FILE_H
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"

std::string String_One()
{
    return "Hello, world!";
}

std::string String_Two()
{
    return "Hello, world!";
}
```

При этом в проекте сборки dll, должен присутствовать DEFINE MYLIBRARY

Для Qt-creator для этого нужно в pro-файл добавить DEFINES += MYLIBRARY

В Visual Studio в настройках проекта С/С++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions просто в конце добавить MYLIBRARY.

Стоит помнить, что библиотеки, в которых используются не только встроенные типы (char, int, float, double, bool, long), а и что-то другое(в том числе и std::string) требуют использования в основной программе(откуда загружается библиотека) использования того же компилятора, в случае с visual c++ еще и требуется соблюдения версии vc10, vc12, vc14 и пр. Так как разные компиляторы могут формировать разные имена экспортируемым функциям.

Если нужно использовать функции из других языков программирования, или с другим компилятором, или с помощью динамической загрузки библиотеки и использования GetProcAddress. То в h файле должны быть только объявления с использованием встроенных типов: (char, int, float, double, bool, long) и с добавлением extern "C", например:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#if defined(MYLIBRARY)
    #define LIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define LIBRARY_EXPORT
#endif

extern "C" int LIBRARY_EXPORT Val_One();
extern "C" int LIBRARY_EXPORT Val_Two();

#endif // FILE_H
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"


int Val_One()
{
    return 0;
}

int Val_Two()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Для того чтоб использовать функции в проекте c#^

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("untitled.dll", EntryPoint = "Val_Two")]
        public static extern int func1();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(func1());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

При этом не забыть подложить untitled.dll в папку с программой c#

Comment: В Вашем случае, при использовании этой библиотеки - каким образом ее подключить в c# проекте и использовать например метод String_One() ?

Comment: String_One() - никак. Нужно использовать char * вместо std::string в паре с extern "C". Второй вариант с Val_One() можно использовать с c#.

Comment: Покажите на примере пожалуйста

Comment: @Елизавета обновил

Comment: а как вернуть переменную string (не int)  ?

Comment: @Елизавета Используйте const char* вместо std::string. Другие способы еще сложнее и проблематичней.

Comment: Где их использовать?  extern "C" int LIBRARY_EXPORT Val_One(); - или тут  -  int Val_One()
{
    return 0;
}      ?

Comment: Решила сама, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что более крректно будет оставить правки тут. Пошагове руковдство создания DLL на С++ под VS [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235636.aspx)
ниже приведены правки по коду 
***File.h***

```
    #ifndef FILE_EXPORTS
#define  FILE_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define FILE_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif


#include "Windows.h"
#include "WowSuite.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace File 

class string_get
{
 public:    

    static std::string String_One();
    static std::string String_Two();

 }
```

***File.cpp***

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "File.h" 
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
namespace File 
          {
            string string_get::String_One()
            {
                return "Hello, world!";
            }
            string string_get::String_Two()
            {
                return "Hello, world!";
            }    
          }
```

Answer (score -3):

Зарубил видео на примере Menu игры [**Создание dll на С++**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mtR4e20Lfo)

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <clocale>
  #include <Windows.h>


   using namespace std;
    #include "DARKLIB.h"

    namespace nmspace
    {
    void darkclass::Crap()
     {

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);


    COORD cd;
    cd.X = 30;
    cd.Y = 5;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hd, cd);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);






    // 1. Intro
    // 2.how mach x+k ??
    // 3. exit


    int m = 0;
    cout << " M E N U" << endl;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_GREEN | 
    FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "1. Intro" << endl;

    cout << "2. 'result n' " << endl;

    cout << "3. 'EXIT' " << endl;


    cin >> m;

    switch (m)

    {
    case 1:

        cout << "Game copyright by Den" << endl;
        break;


     case 2:

        int n;
        int x;
        int k;

        cout << "Plz enter x=";
        cin >> x;

        cout << "Plz ener k=";
        cin >> k;

        n = x + k;

        cout << "You result n=" << n;
        break;

    case 3:  cout << "Exit press key" << endl;

        break;

    default:
        cout << " wrong menu option" << endl;
        _getch();


    }
    system("pause");
     }
   }
```

Comment: Если цель, поднять количество просмотров на Ютубе, то вы здесь не найдёте поддержки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите непосредственно в тексте ответа, из каких общедоступных источников можно получить используемый вами `"DARKLIB.h"`; или если он не слишком крупный, приведите его содержимое прямо в ответе. Без него ответ не является самодостаточным.

Comment: А за что мне дизов налепили ? Я только зарегался на форуме а меня уже травят =) Все же работает. Какие то злодеи просто

Comment: @0101010 а я предупреждал. И нет, моего "диза" (или, как у нас говорят "минуса") среди них нет.